# How to set target for zoomed image in jQuery zoom plugin by Jack Moore

Tags: jquery, zooming, colorbox

I'm using both the zoom and colorbox plugins by Jack Moore. I've got everything working fine except for being able to specify a different target area for the zoomed image to display in.

The settings documentation on this page: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ says,

"target false   A selector or DOM element that should be used as the parent container for the zoomed image."

I've tried setting it like any other option, but I'm not having any luck. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#target-img').zoom({magnify:2,
            callback: function(){
                $(this).colorbox({href: this.src, magnify: 2, target: '#zoom-window'});
            }
});
```

});

The zoomed image stays in the parent container.  See this fiddle for a full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/MFrV3/2/

Comment: target is a .zoom option so it should be outside the callback like this [http://jsfiddle.net/MFrV3/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/MFrV3/3/)

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamUribe Stupid mistake on my part putting the reference to target in the call to colorbox. I knew better than that. The syntax for getting the selector to pass as the target is what was stumping me. I'd never have thought about .get(), and I couldn't find any examples. With your example, I updated the click event, too. Now zoom works correctly, but not colorbox. Could that be because $(this) in the callback no longer references the correct element because the $("#zoom-window).get(0) selector changes it? 
http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/MFrV3/6/
http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/MFrV3/7/

Comment: $('#target-img') is not a img tag so you need to get the img inside #target-img and get the attr("src") [http://jsfiddle.net/MFrV3/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/MFrV3/15/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Perfect! If you care to add your input as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the target option only apply to the .zoom plugin not the .colorbox so you need to set the target in the .zoom call like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target-img').zoom({    
           magnify:2,
           target:$("#zoom-window").get(0)//target need to be the html element 
    }).colorbox({href: $("img",this).attr("src")});//you can chain the colorbox call
    //get attr src of the img inside the target-img
});
```

to get the src of the img you need to get the actual img inside the #target-img div and to retrieve the src you need to use .attr
http://jsfiddle.net/MFrV3/15/

Comment: For anyone interested, the completed Zoom and Colorbox setup, incorporating @Abraham's answer, can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/MFrV3/16/